# Get all checked value from the table

Tags: java

I'm trying to get all value from a table where the checkbox is checked, I've make codes but it only gets one output and not working if I checked randomly you have to start checking from the start to make it work.

This the Output I need:

[image: This the Output i need]

this my current codes I've make:

```
TableModel model = table_test.getModel();
 for(int i=0; i<model.getRowCount();++i)
 {
 Boolean isChecked = Boolean.valueOf(model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());    
 String col = model.getValueAt(i,1).toString();
  if (isChecked==true) {
      try{
      textarea.setText(col);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }
 }     
 }
```

this codes only display is one value at the text area.

I hope you can help me with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can try below.





  TableModel model = table_test.getModel();

     for(int i=0; i<model.getRowCount();++i)
     {
     Boolean isChecked = Boolean.valueOf(model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());    
     String col = model.getValueAt(i,1).toString();
      if (isChecked==true) {
          try{
           textarea.append(col);

         } catch (Exception e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
         }
     }     
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but your codes output continues in one line my ideal output list of numbers downwards and if i checked it randomly  doesn't work you should try right at the beginning to make it work.

Comment: You can use append method of textarea like above, I have edited the answer please try.

Comment: Thanks is working i have output downwards but if i chose randomly example i chose the lower part of the value in table this code doesn't work

Comment: Could you please provide the screen shots of your table and its data also please do mentioned what is expected and what is the current output.

Comment: my screenshot is above right at the link a gave that is my desire output. the current output is null is i chose randomly.

Comment: Sorry, But I am bit of confused with word randomly here ? You said earlier it is working of one of your scenario could you please also attached that screenshot too.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBhBQ.png this is my ideal output in your codes if  I checked the number 17  only its not working . but if i chose the one one top your codes it worked.